# SQL/SQlite: Adding a column in a select statement based on a value of another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the columns `word, length, position, count and definition`.
I want to make a select of `word` and `definition` but just keeping the definition of some words (based on a condition over `position`, `count` and `length`) and the rest of definitions replace them by an empty string.

I'm doing the following query:

```
SELECT word,definition FROM (SELECT word, definition, position, count FROM words 
WHERE position = 5000 AND count < 5 AND length <= 6
AND definition IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT word, "" AS definition, position, count FROM words)
ORDER BY position ASC, count DESC
```

But I end up with duplicated values in the column word.
How can I get this without duplicated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the inverse WHERE clause to your second set?

```
SELECT word,definition FROM
(
  SELECT word, definition, position, count FROM words 
  WHERE position = 5000 AND count < 5 AND length <= 6
  AND definition IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT word, "" AS definition, position, count FROM words
  WHERE NOT (position = 5000 AND count < 5 AND length <= 6
             AND definition IS NOT NULL)
)
ORDER BY position ASC, count DESC
```

Comment: Why not use `CASE WHEN (condition) THEN definition ELSE "" END` ?

Answer (score 0):

A  `SELECT DISTINCT` seems to solve your problem.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: No, DISCTINCT does not work here because no rows are duplicated. I get duplicated values in the column word.

Comment: Ok i  red to quickly your SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You could use group by clause....

Answer (score 0):

Use of UNION SELECT seems to be useless in your case.
It seems that you want only to initialize definition column when it is `NULL`.
Definition is only part of your outputs.

Use a `ifnull` to initialize definition :

```
SELECT word, IFNULL(definition,"") FROM words 
  WHERE position = 5000 AND count < 5 AND length <= 6
ORDER BY position ASC, count DESC
```

**IFNULL** will return definition is definition is not NULL and "" otherwise.

SQLITE ISNULL Documentation
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

MYSQL IsNULL Documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: If possible you could prefer `COALESCE()` to IFNULL, which can have a variable number of arguments (and you should link to [the SQLite documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) as the question is tagged SQLite, not MySQL)